# PageEvent is throwing Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, itext

When the PageEvent is added to generate the Header and Footer, it seems to be trying to write to the stream after it is closed.  I'm not sure where to put the page event.  If I remove the page event, it generates the pdf fine.

`p.Parse(html);` is where the "Cannot access a closed Stream" fails.  Removing the `writer.PageEvent` will cause the Parse to work but then it won't generate a header/footer.

I used [this](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers) page as a reference for the header/footer code.

Code:

```
try {
  using(var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    using(var document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 20 f, 20 f, 5 f, 5 f)) {
      using(var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream)) {
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        writer.PageEvent = new HeaderFooter(Header, Footer); // if I remove this it generates fine but then I don't get a header/footer.

        var tagProcessors = (DefaultTagProcessorFactory) Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
        tagProcessors.RemoveProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG); // remove the default processor
        tagProcessors.AddProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG, new CustomImageTagProcessor()); // use our new processor
        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(tagProcessors);

        ICSSResolver CssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
        CssResolver.AddCss(Css, true);
        IPipeline pipeline =
         new CssResolverPipeline(CssResolver,
          new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext,
           new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);

        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

        document.Open();

        using(var html = new StringReader(HtmlData)) {
         p.Parse(html);  // <-- ERROR thrown here
        }
       // close document   tried docoment.Close();  same issue
      }
    }

  // get bytes from stream  
  pdf = stream.ToArray();
 }
}
```

Here is the page event:

```
public class HeaderFooter: PdfPageEventHelper {
 protected ElementList header;
 protected ElementList footer;
 private string _footerText;
 private string _headerText;

 public HeaderFooter(string headerText, string footerText) {
  header = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(headerText, null);
  footer = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(footerText, "table { font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; }");
  _footerText = footerText;
  _headerText = headerText;
 }

 public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

  try {

   footer = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(_footerText.Replace("@PageNumber", writer.PageNumber.ToString()), "table { font-size: 8px; font-style: italic; }");
   ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
   ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 832, 559, 810));
   foreach(IElement e in header) {
    ct.AddElement(e);
   }
   ct.Go();
   ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 10, 559, 32));

   foreach(IElement e in footer) {
    ct.AddElement(e);
   }
   ct.Go();



  } catch (DocumentException de) {
   throw new Exception();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Using 5.5.5.0 (which is what I have locally available) I get en exception on one of the `using` closing braces. However, if I uncomment the `document.Close()` method after the `StringReader` block it works as expected.

Comment: Your `{...} catch (DocumentException de) {
   throw new Exception();
  }` hides any information that `DocumentException` may contain. Log the `DocumentException` and **don't** throw a `new Exception()`. Furthermore do as @kuujinbo proposes and move the `PdfWriter` out of the `using`. The `PdfWriter` automatically is closed by closing or disposing the `document`. Not every instance of a disposable should be put into a `using` statement...

Comment: The PDF generates fine whether I have a using or not until I add the PageEvent.   The error generated with the pageevent and no using is `iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline cries, it cannot find it's own context."}iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline cries, it cannot find it's own context`

Comment: *"The PDF generates fine whether I have a using or not until I add the PageEvent."* - Maybe. But if there is an exception, superfluous or wrong `using` statements can easily hide the actual exception with an exception triggered during disposal. *"The error generated with the pageevent and no using is..."* - Ah, that is something to work with; can you share the stack trace of that error?.

Comment: Your `HeaderFooter` method `OnEndPage` contains a `return` at the start, so it essentially does nothing.

Comment: After pulling the `PdfWriter` out of the `using`, removing that weird `return` statement, and changing the header positions to somewhere in the visible page area, I could fill many pages with your code. Thus, I assume there is yet another issue, probably with the HTML you use, maybe something else. So please update your sample code to make it complete (yet short) to allow reproducing your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the html that is being used.  Although the page generated a PDF completely fine without the header, it would fail when the header was added.  The usings and returns were fine.

Comment: *"The usings and returns were fine."* - No, they are not, not all of them at least. They may not be a problem in the positive case but in case of an exception they make the situation fail worse than necessary.

Comment: I had no problem with the code in my project generating a pdf.  The only problem I had was the header.

Answer (score 1):

Seen similar issues before related to putting a `PdfWriter` in a `using` statement. Here's a simplified example based on your question you can test to reproduce the issue:

```
// ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream))
        {
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Chunk("test"));
        }
    }
    pdf = stream.ToArray();
}
```

that code snippet throws a `ObjectDisposedException`: *Cannot access a closed Stream.* as you've described.

Instead, if `PdfWriter` is `Dispose()`'ed  like this:

```
PdfWriter writer = null;
try
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var document = new Document())
        {
            writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Chunk("test"));
        }
        pdf = stream.ToArray();
    }
}
finally { writer.Dispose(); }
```

all is well. iTextSharp v5.5.8.

Comment: The PDF generates fine until I add the PageEvent in both cases (with or w/o using).  If I remove the page event in both cases the pdf generates fine.   So that being said, the error received with the PageEvent and no using is `iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline cries, it cannot find it's own context."}iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline cries, it cannot find it's own context`

Comment: Actually I would propose not disposing the `writer` at all. When the `document` is disposed, the only non-trivial code executed is the closing of the document listeners, and the `writer` is the *only* listener here.

Comment: @mkl - Completely agree and generally neither put a `PdfWriter` in a `using` statement, nor call `Dispose()` explicitly, but was going on the premise that the OP had his reasons. i.e. organizational coding standards that mandate all classes that implement `IDisposable` shall be disposed.